# Please make a legal tag

Tags: discussion, tagwiki

Someone with reputation score 300+ please make a tag for questions about formatting legal documents using TeX/LaTeX.  Perhaps make it `legal-style`?  I am feeling the lack of such a tag.

Suggested description:

> Tag {legal-style} is for questions concerning (La)TeX and the exacting requirements of style guides (The McGill Guide, Bluebook, Australian Guide to Legal Citation, and many others) for legal documents and their citations.

[Help Center:  Create tags](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags)

Comment: I have added a tag "legal-style" (and applied it to one question that appeared suitable).  I included the bare-bones information regarding its use, but it could benefit from a fuller description.  If you can provide suitable text, I'll be happy to add that too.  (You can edit such text into your question here, and ping me to do the update.)

Comment: I added a suggested description.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Done!  Mission accomplished.  Thank you.

Comment: For convenience, here is a link the new tag: [tag:legal-style].